# SharePoint 2016 installation: Error 1310

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, windows-server

Clean Windows 2012R2 Standard (not even in domain), during installation of SharePoint 2016 next error occurs:

> Product: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2016 Core -- Error 1310.
>   Error writing to file:
>   microsoft.o365.resourcecatalog.pulsepackage.dll.   System error 0. 
>   Verify that you have access to that directory.

During installation this manual was used: http://andreasglaser.com/blog/install-sharepoint-2016

All Windows Updates are installed. Using `Prerequprerequisiteinstaller.exe` from sharepoint installation disk all additional software installed. Office 2010 are installed correctly.

Steps made to resolve problem (with no result):

- PSModuePath are OK (no extra " in string)
- Office 2010 repair was made
- msiexec /unreg && msiexec /regserver done
- Run As administrator for setup.exe of SharePoint Differnet installation pathes tried

What else can be done to complete setup normally?

Comment: Error occuried due to corrupted SharePoint installation.

Answer (score 1):

**First,** It is **not supported** to install and Configure SharePoint without using a domain controller. you will face more issues like the directory permission issue moreover, the Users & Groups, People Picker will not work!

**In your case,** you should first

- Join your machine to the domain this start install and configure the SharePoint.
- Make sure that the SharePoint installation media is located ub a physical. drive

> **Note:** if it's a dev machine, you can install the domain in the same machine but  It is not recommended to install the Domain
>   Controller and SharePoint on the same server in **Production** that
>   will effect on performance.